# JSON exception preventing android build

Tags: android, json, exception, processing

I am new to android, json, processing and stackoverflow, so please bear with me. I took some processing code, made sure it worked, and tried to create an android apk. I have one error that is unresolved. I have a function, int getFeedLength(). It has to catch an exception, and returns a null.

Every time I return a null (replacing it with anything else fails), the Android build fails, and I have looked at a lot of online resources to no avail.

Is there an alternate way to return null, or something else that will allow the build to proceed? I tried float and double, and they all resulted in other types of errors.

Here is the function, if need be, I can share the entire processing sketch:

```
int getFeedLength() {
    int result;
    String response = loadStrings(BASE_URL + APIKEY)[0];

    if (response != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray feeds = root.getJSONArray("feeds");
            result = feeds.length();
            println("number of feed entries: " + result);
            return result;
        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to perform action such an such");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\SYAMAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\android3618104784291490945.pde\src\changethispackage\beforesubmitting\tothemarket\app\app.java:248: incompatible types
[javac] found   : <nulltype>
[javac] required: int
[javac] return null;
```

Comment: Which exact line is 248?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return null` write `return 0` cause you have set return type to `int` *returning 0 will be more comfortable* at the end to know that is there any feeds or not.

Comment: Hello Soni, if I return zero, I get errors suggesting the catch is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to make the returning type of the getFeedLength() method a Integer?
Something like this:

```
Integer getFeedLength() {
```

Hpe it helps.

Comment: Hello, I tried that, it did not help. When I use integer, I get an error for every line in the function. Thanks!